# Multiple annotation classes in map view

Tags: ios7, annotations, mkmapview

How do i add several annotation classes to my map application. I would like each class to have a different pin color.

Comment: Please be more specific about what doesn't work (exact errors, warnings, behavior, etc) and show some representative code.  What exactly happens when you try "implement the second class into the nsarray"?  Edit your question with more details and some code.

Comment: you are absolutely right. i should have been more clear. what i really want to know is how to have multiple annotation classes show pins on a map

Comment: As long as each class implements the MKAnnotation protocol, there is no problem.  In viewForAnnotation, set the pinColor based on the annotation parameter's class itself or some property of the annotation.  Use isKindOfClass and casting.  Show what you've tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks Anna... i was able to fix it @Anna

Answer (score 0):

try this also it will help you [OC MapView With Annotations](https://github.com/yinkou/OCMapView)

hope it will works right.